# Cannot upload docx files to server using upload library

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

An 'invalid file type' error occours when i try to upload a docx file to server using codeignitor upload function but it works fine in local server and also in case of pdf,doc and image files .

Below is my file upload script .

I use ajaxuploader to upload file

```
<script>
    //.......................FILE UPLOAD ...........................................
    $(function(){ 

        var btnUpload=$('#nefile');
        new AjaxUpload(btnUpload, {
            action: '<?php echo site_url('userdashboard/saveabstractdocument'); ?>',
            name: 'file',

            onComplete: function(file, response){

                if(response)
                {

                    if(response == 1){


                        $('#abstractdoc').css('display','none');
                        $('#abstractval').css('display','block');



                    }else{


                        //$('#metaimgval_error').html("");
                        $("#val").val(response);
                        $('#abstractval').css('display','none');
                    }


                } else
                {

                }
            }
        }); 
    });
    //.......................FILE UPLOAD ENDS...........................................

</script>
```

below is my controller function

```
 function saveabstractdocument() { 
        $abstractfile = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        $filenme = $_FILES["file"]["name"];

        $ext = explode(".", $filenme);
        $cnt = count($ext) - 1;
        $filenme = date("m") . date("d") . date("Y") . time() . "." . $ext[$cnt];
        $fil = date("m") . date("d") . date("Y") . time();
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/abstract/';
        $config['file_name'] = $fil;
        $config['allowed_types'] ='pdf|doc|docx';
        $config['max_size'] = '';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload("file")) {
            $data["err"] = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
           // print_r($this->upload->display_errors());exit;
            echo 1;
        } else {
            $this->load->library('session');
            $datafile = array
                (
                'fname' => $filenme
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($datafile);

            echo $abstractfile;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don'y you use like this in view...

```
<input type="file" name="file"/>
```

or in your question invalid type maybe its not included in your mimes.php the doc,pdf,docx
and your $config['max_size'] = ''; if you will not put any value you can remove that.

also here my sample of upload file

```
$config['upload_path']   = './files/contracts-csv/'; 
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'csv';   
                $config['max_size']      = '4096';      
                $config['overwrite']     =  TRUE;

                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                $this->upload->display_errors('', '');

                if (!$this->upload->do_upload("csv_file")) {
                      echo $this->upload->display_errors(); die();
                      $this->data['error'] = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                } else {
                    $upload_result = $this->upload->data(); 
                    $pathfile = $upload_result['full_path'];
                }
```

...Hopes i give you idea